# How come Maven can generate the `effective pom` but fails to generate the `dependency list`?

Tags: maven, dependencies, effective-pom

I was playing with a Maven project when I recognized that:

`$mvn help:effective-pom` leads to **BUILD SUCCESS**

However

`$mvn dependency:list` leads to **BUILD FAILURE**

As far I understand, the effective pom includes a detailed list of dependencies as well. So what `dependency:list` is trying to output can actually be found in effective pom.

Can someone explain what is my misunderstanding?

---

---

**To replicate the problem:**

`$git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/naver/pinpoint.git
$cd pinpoint
$mvn clean help:effective-pom
$mvn clean dependency:list`

---

The full error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project pinpoint-commons: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.navercorp.pinpoint:pinpoint-commons:jar:1.7.2-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.navercorp.pinpoint:pinpoint-thrift:jar:1.7.2-SNAPSHOT in https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of cloudera has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is based on problems. Either you have defined a dependency which is not available any more (which could be the case by using SNAPSHOT's) or you have not configured the repository correctly (access problems firewall / proxy ?) ...Furthermore the difference is that `:effective-pom` creates the pom's file from your projects pom's with inheritance etc. whereas `dependency:list` resolves dependencies which shows problems by configuration proxies/firewalls cause it tries to access this dependencies.

So I would check the usage of the com.navercorp.pinpoint dependency etc. cause it does not exist in the repository nor in any you have configured nor that I think that a SNAPSHOT is a good idea to rely on...